# Facebook opengraph is not posting in user Timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

using open graph i am trying to post `username shared an event on Appname`. in my facebook account wall.

it gets successfully posted in ticker and in activities, but it is not posting in Timeline.

Following is my php code which i am using for sharing purpose

```
$params = array('Objectname'=>'object_url');
$facebook->api( '/'.$fb_user_id.'/AppNamespace:Actiontypename','post', $params );
```

What to be added to share in time line using open graph

Comment: Do you see the actions in the app timeline https://www.facebook.com/USER_ID_OR_USERNAME/app_APP_ID ?

Comment: @Lego yes, its coming in the apps timeline, but i want it in the user's timeline...

Comment: @vicky Is this line is a message you want to post in user's timeline `'/'.$fb_user_id.'/AppNamespace:Actiontypename'`

Comment: Which was the solution @vicky?

Comment: @vrunoa add 'fb:explicitly_shared'=>'true'

Comment: @vicky I submit my open graph action to facebook because they have to approve it first. But in theory, this is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses the so called 'GraphRank' to determine whether to show or not to show a published action or aggregation on the user's timeline.

The calculation goes like this:

> GraphRank = affinity * weight * interactions * time

- affinity (score): this is the relationship between the viewing user and the creator of the action.
- weight: if two users interact frequently with each other, the respective actions in the open graph are rated higher than for users who do not have the same interest and are not in close contact on Facebook.
- interactions: how often does the user interact with the application and how do friends react to the activities in the social channels (if nobody clicks on the published actions it's bad for the GraphRank).
- time: if an app is used irregularly or only once, actions will receive less attention in the long run and will be presented less prominently on the timeline.

See this article: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/12/27/edgerank-and-graph-rank-defined/

In order to see your published action on your timeline just try to interact intensively with your app i.e. by publishing more stories (and like those with some test users).